# map.fitbounds not doing anything

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zooming, bounds, fitbounds

I have a script which takes data from html and uses it to plot routes on a map. I'm trying to get it to take all the routes and zoom to show all of them. Here's the code:

```js
var ombounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); //bounds
    for (var r=1; $("#master-master > div").length; r++)
    {
        // Add a placemark at the start of each route
        var placemark_id = "#master-" + r + " > #placemarks-data > #placemark-0";

        var markerParameters = {};
        markerParameters.index = r-1;
        markerParameters.total = $(placemark_id + " > .total").html();
        markerParameters.mapData = $(placemark_id + " > .map").html();
        markerParameters.instructionsData = $("#master-" + r + " > #snippet").html();
        markerParameters.distanceData = $("#master-" + r + " > #distance").html();
        markerParameters.durationData = $("#master-" + r + " > #duration").html();
        markerParameters.titleData = $("#master-" + r + " > #title").html();
        markerParameters.urltitleData = $("#master-" + r + " > #url-title").html();
        markerParameters.imageData = $(placemark_id + " > .image").html();

        $.OverMap.addMarker(markerParameters);

        // Draw route
        var points = new Array();
        var pointsData = [];
        var pointsData = $('#master-' + r + ' > #route-data').html();
        if (pointsData != '')
        {
            var pointsArray = JSON.parse(pointsData);
            for (var p=0; p<pointsArray.length; p++) {
                var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(pointsArray[p][0], pointsArray[p][1]);
                points.push(pt);
                ombounds.extend(pt); //bounds
            }
            $.OverMap.drawRoute(points);

        }
        else $.OverMap.drawDirections({preserveViewport:false});
    }
    (map.getBounds()); //bounds
    map.fitBounds(ombounds); //bounds
```

For some reason, map.fitBounds(ombounds) does nothing. The code still plots the routes, but I can't see what the bounds related functions are doing. I've added //bounds to all the lines related to the zooming - at the moment, they have no visible affect on the code's output. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Why do you have preserveViewport set to false?

Comment: The code was originally made by another developer

Comment: If you are maintaining it _you_ need to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

When the `preserveViewport` option of the directions service is set to false, each call to the DirectionsRenderer will zoom and center the map on its result.  If you want fitBounds to override it, you need to set that to true.

Comment: Well how about that. I was ignoring that line the whole time. Nevertheless, it still doesn't work even if I set it to true.

Comment: Can you provide enough code to replicate the problem?  Or a jsfiddle that does?

Comment: I don't think I can, seeing as it takes arrays from a database backend.

Comment: How about a link to your map? Or debugging it yourself by testing the coordinates before adding them to the bounds object?  Or looking at your database and verifying all the rows contain valid coordinates?  Or capturing a set of coordinates from your database and hardcoding them into an example that shows the problem?